# MVC 6 upgrade in VS 2015RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I upgraded a VS2015RC MVC 6 web project (DNVM) from beta5 to beta6 and upgraded all dependencies to beta5 that I could.  After many tiny tweaks, I am down to one issue, I think.  After chasing the configuration changes in startup I found the signature of the Startup method changed and includes an interface that wont resolve.

Error   CS0433  The type 'IApplicationEnvironment' exists in both 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' Web.DNX 4.5.1   D:\Repositories\Web\Startup.cs  35

I tried adding with nuget the beta4 Abstractions and Interfaces but neither worked.

What assembly did i miss to upgrade or add to the project?

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, **IApplicationEnvironment** appEnv)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
               .AddJsonFile("config.json")
               .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracked it down.

Just use "Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5" in project.json and remove the interfaces dependency if its there.

My project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CommandLineUtils": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Ini": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",

  },
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on this as I am running into a similar problem and your answer doesn't really help much. Where is this removed from? the project.json or project.lock.json?

Comment: add to project.json and make sure the Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interface one is removed.

Comment: I've double checked my project.json and I've never had a Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interface, but I have added "Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5" and I still can't make your fix work :\

Comment: I'll add my project.json dependencies section

Comment: *sigh* this is what I get for using a beta product, I was missing all of the Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.* dependencies. I appreciate the help on this!

Comment: You should probably also remove "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5" - and the associated app.UseBrowserLink(); in your startup class. The ASP.Net vNext team have said that Browser Link is not currently working with beta5.

Comment: I will remove it from the above post.  I have it commented out in the startup.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this working myself, the above answer is missing one part about some minor changes also needed to Startup.cs, hopefully this helps others upgrade from beta4 to beta5:

In project.json dependencies add this:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",
    ...
  },
```

In your Startup.cs make sure you have the following using:

```
using Microsoft.Framework.Runtime;
```

The startup method would look like this (including the `.Build()` at the end which is also needed now.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{               
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
```